# Azure API Gateway: Remove a attribute label from JSON

Tags: json, azure

In azure API gateway I want to remove "content":

From below example:

From this:

```json
{
  "content": {
    "product": "apple",
    "productcode": "12345566",
    "details": [
      {
        "issuedId": 16294,
        "IssuesTo": "CAND",
        "Description": "Replacement",
        "created": "2016-02-24T05:51:56",
        "occurred": "2016-02-24T05:49:47.000EST",
        "IssuedBy": "James"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

to this:

```json
{
    "product": "apple",
    "productcode": "12345566",
    "details": [
      {
        "issuedId": 16294,
        "IssuesTo": "CAND",
        "Description": "Replacement",
        "created": "2016-02-24T05:51:56",
        "occurred": "2016-02-24T05:49:47.000EST",
        "IssuedBy": "James"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have tried searching most of the recommendations are to serialize the object in the code. Can I do the same through Azure API gateway if best how. Please can someone guide me to right direction?

Comment: well, you can execute arbitrary c# code in API Management using policies

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this functionality out of the box in Azure API Management, Unfortunately.
[MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-reference) lists all possible policies that can be used in Azure API Management, and none of them can perform this task.

The possible workaround is to use a service to translate this JSON. An Azure function or LogicApp maybe.

Answer (score 0):

> Here's a very simple solution:

You can create a simple logical flow through the [LogicApps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/) designer on Azure.
I created one taking your sample JSON request body and specifying the response JSON to match what you were looking for and I got it running pretty easily. I tested it out with postman by sending HTTP POST with the sample request JSON to the URL that LogicApps will provide you when you design one. I only used the Request and Response triggers and actions and nothing else.

> The LogicApp flow should look like:

[image: This Screenshot]

> When I tested through postman, I sent your JSON as my HTTP POST and I
>   got the response JSON in the desired format:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, it can be easily achieved with outbound policies, e.g.:

```
<set-body>
@{
    JObject inBody = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>();
    return inBody["content"].ToString();
}
</set-body>
```